# Cassandra multi-column Filtering

Tags: database, cassandra, schema, nosql

After a lot of searching I cannot find good documentation on "many-to-many" relationships which I want to filter multiple values on.

I will use games as an example

```
Games have 1 to many Distributors
Games have 1 to many Producers
Games have 1 to many Developers
```

my goal is find all games which have filters on distributor, producer or developers.

now from research, I can use the "in" operator, although I have read that is not the recommended practice due to one node reaching out to multiple nodes, instead of the server simply reaching out to those nodes directly. (correct me if I am wrong)

now the question I have is, how granular should I go with the data?

do I simply need this, then cross reference the results locally?

```
GamesByDistributor
GamesByProducer
GamesByDeveloper
```

or should I get even more granular like this:

```
GamesByDistributorANDProducer
GamesByDistributorANDDeveloper
GamesByDeveloperANDProducer
GamesByDeveloperProducerANDDistributor
```

the granular options would allow me to query on 1 to all of the items and all of their combinations to get back only the items I want, instead of cross referencing the values from each of the Distributor, producer and developer partitions.

is this recommended, or are there better ways to handle this specific situation?

Answer (score 1):

You can model 1-to-many via the various collection data types (there are some limitations on volumes). Have you tried that?

The best way to model your data is by your queries so, potentially yes - the even more granular approach you mention might be appropriate (remember writes are cheap).

Another option would be to look at a (kindof) bitmap index based around your partition keys.

You can also look at secondary indexes - Depending on your version you could use SASI indexes (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA/component/12328927/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:component-summary-panel) or even a lucene approach via https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index or DataStax Enterprise Search.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have thought of collections, but I want to avoid the "in" clause as I am uneasy about the possibilities of future limitations and single point of failures.

I will look into bitmaps, although I am not sure how they will apply in my specific situation, they key would have to be rather large.

does SASI indexes fix the issue with this:
https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/09/22/cassandra-query-patterns-not-using-the-in-query-for-multiple-partitions/

as I want to be able to say 'Where Developer in ('Nintendo', 'Sega')' and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider DSE Graph or Open Source Titan for your data model.

Comment: I just looked into graph databases as I didn't really understand them (until I just now researched it.) so if I go the graph route, does that mean I would always use the Graph Query Language would it be a complete replacement or would I want to use CQL when graph is not performant? How do people usually decide when to use CQL and when to use Graph Query Language? Example would be great!